# Having trouble adding environment variable

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3

I am running my web apps under `www-data`.  But I need to add a secret key.  How do I add the secret key for the `www-data` user.

I have tried `sudo -u www-data export SECRET_KEY="This Is my key"`

I am getting the error `sudo: export command not found.`

Answer (score 1):

Add the environment variable to the login shell ~/.profile file of this user.

Comment: I am getting errors `sudo -u www-data vi ~/.profile` When I try to add `SECRET_KEY="this is my ke"` I get an error `warning changing a read-only file`

Comment: "~" means "home directory of the user.  If you don't happen to be user "www-data", then you instead need to type `sudo -u www-data vi ~www-data/.profile`

Comment: I was suggesting that perhaps `~/.profile` and `~www-data/.profile` are *TWO DIFFERENT FILES*.  It depends on which user you're logged in as :)  In any case: a) make sure you've got the right file, then b) make sure it has "+w" write permissions.  ALSO: do you really want to be writing some "SECRET KEY" - in clear text - to your .profile????

Comment: Since I am not the admin and the admin refuses to add to the `~/.profile` I added an environment variable to my startup script.